# Order by com union

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho as seguintes tabelas:

```
Pessoa1
Id  |    Nome      |  Cidade
1   |   José       |São Paulo
2   |   Maria      |Rio de Janeiro

Pessoa2
Id  |    Nome      |  Cidade
1   |   Pedro      |Belo Horizonte
2   |   Ana        |Vitória
```

Tenho o seguinte select:

```
SELECT * FROM (

    SELECT
          p1.Nome
          ISNULL(CAST(p1.Nome AS VARCHAR),'') + ';' + 
          ISNULL(CAST(p1.Cidade AS VARCHAR),'') AS Resultado
    FROM Pessoa1 p1

    UNION

    SELECT
          p2.Nome
          ISNULL(CAST(p2.Nome AS VARCHAR),'') + ';' + 
          ISNULL(CAST(p2.Cidade AS VARCHAR),'') AS Resultado
    FROM Pessoa1 p2

) AS Resultado
ORDER BY Resultado.Nome
```

O objetivo é trazer a coluna `Resultado` com os valores separados por ponto e vírgula, **respeitando a ordem alfabética** através da coluna `Nome`.

A questão é que eu gostaria que a coluna `Nome` não aparecesse ao executar o `select`, pois a mesma já está incluída na coluna `Resultado`. Existe alguma forma?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você está utilizando o seletor `*`, que significa *todos os campos*. Mude sua SQL de:

```
SELECT * FROM (
```

para

```
SELECT Resultado FROM (
```

Assim apenas este campo será retornado.

Comment: Como não vi isso antes?! Muito obrigado! Falta de atenção minha...

Comment: Pensei nisso, mas só isso já ordenaria o resultado pela coluna `Nome` ?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown não, porém a última parte do *statement* é: `ORDER BY Resultado.Nome`, guarantindo assim a ordenação.

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues sem estresse, acontece com os melhores entre nós. =)